# MagicalRecord Find(All) doesn't find objects from relationships sometimes

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

The objects from relationship just gone when I close the simulator and reopen it or push and pop some view controllers. I still can get the objects when I first save the objects to core data.

This is the code to save objects to core data:

```
for (NSDictionary *obj in results) {
    Stock *stock = [Stock MR_createEntity];
    stock.name = obj[@"name"];
    NSArray *categories = obj[@"categories"];
    if ([categories count] > 0) {
        for (NSDictionary *category in categories) {
            StockCategory *stockCategory = [StockCategory MR_createEntity];
            stockCategory.categoryId = category[@"_id"];
            stockCategory.name = category[@"name"];
            [stock addCategoriesObject:stockCategory];
        }
    }
}
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    self.stocks = [Stock MR_findAllSortedBy:@"createdDate" ascending:NO];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}];
```

Below code is to retrieve object from core data:

```
self.stocks = [Stock MR_findAllSortedBy:@"createdDate" ascending:NO];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

If I close the simulator, and re launch it, I get objects from core data but the stock's StockCategory array is empty. I recall it when I first save the stock to the core data, the stock's StockCategory array is not empty. Why when I relaunch the simulator, the objects from relationships just gone.

The model:
Stock.h

```
@class StockCategory;

@interface Stock : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *categories;
@end

@interface Stock (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addCategoriesObject:(StockCategory *)value;
- (void)removeCategoriesObject:(StockCategory *)value;
- (void)addCategories:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeCategories:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

StockCategory.h

```
@class Stock;

@interface StockCategory : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Stock *stock;

@end
```

Comment: Was "categories" from the beginning in your model (`xcdatamodel`)? Did you try a clean/uninstall/reinstall of the app? When you change some kind of things in CoreData, you may have to do some clean (if you did some change of your `xcdatamodel`).

Comment: Does the completion block of `MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:` get run before you quit?  It sounds like it's an asynchronous method.